# how can i know if a student was in the campus? edit: using first order logic(logic)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

i don't understand this at all. how can i deduct if a student was at the campus?

EDIT: i tried to convert all of the following into a first order logic in a closed domain (and some closed world assumptions) to better understand the subject, i.e: if we know that Helen is a professor, then only helen is a professor can be inferred from the statement).

sorry for the change, but it is very important for me to do it like this so i can learn it correctly and methodically. i also tried to put the sentences into first order logic like i asked here

i know that:

1. every professor counsels at least one student

$\forall x,y(C(x,y) \land \forall x,y -> (x=p \land y=(\exists S(s)))$

2. Helen is a professor

$\exists x(P(x) \land x-> x='Helen')$

3. every student has a counselor, who is a professor

$\forall x,y(H(x,y) \land \forall x,y(x=s \land y=c) \land c -> p)$

4. counseling meeting occur at the campus

$\exists x,y(occurs(x,y) \land  \forall x,y ((x=m \land i) \land y = u)$

5. Leno is a student

$\exists x(S(x) \land x -> x= s)$

6. every counselor meets with all of his counselees(the ones he counsels)

$\forall x,y(M(x,y) \land x=c \land M(x,y) ->  y=h )$ (a counselor meets with all of his counselees, and if he meets someone it must be his counselee)

where:

S(x) - x is a student

P(x) - x is a professor

C(x,y) - x counsels y

M(x,y) - x meets with y

O(x,y) - x occurs at y

H(x,y) - x has y

p - a professor

s - a student

c - a counselor

m - a meeting

h - a counselee

i - a counseling

u - a campus

i don't understand, how can i conclude if helen was at the campus or not?

please help me with that and explain so i can learn and apply what you do on about a dozen more i've got. they had not taught us this well

edit: to make more sense, at least for me, i am trying to "formalize" the given sentences using first order logic to make it simpler, i am hoping the formalization would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the set of all professors, and $S$ the set of all students. You can then interperet the statements as follows:

---

(1) For all $p\in P$, there exists an $s\in S$ such that $p$ counsels $s$. We can term this statement $C$ for 'counsels' and write it symbolically as...

$$\forall p\in P.\exists s\in S:C(p,s)$$

(2) There exists a $p\in P$ such that $p=$Helen. Symbollically...

$$\exists p\in P:p=\text{Helen}$$

or, more succinctly...

$$\text{Helen}\in P$$

(3) For all $s\in S$, there exists a $p\in P$ such that $p$ counsels $s$. Symbollically...
$$\forall s\in S.\exists p\in P:C(p,s)$$

(4) Counseling meetings occurs on campus. We can denote 'counseling occurs on campus' with $L$ for 'location'.

(5) There exists an $s\in S$ such that $s=$Leno. Symbollically...

$$\exists s\in S:s=\text{Leno}$$

or, more succinctly...

$$\text{Leno}\in S$$

(6) For all $p\in P$, there exists a subset $S_p\subseteq S$ such that for all $s\in S_p$, $p$ meets with $S$. We may denote '$p$ meets with $s$' by $M$ for 'meeting. Symbollically...

$$\forall p\in P.\exists S_p\subseteq S:(\forall s\in S_p.M(p,s))$$

---

Let $K(p,s)\equiv\text{$p$ and $s$ are on campus}$.

We want to show that there is some $s$ such that $K(\text{Helen},s)$ is true.

It is clear that $C(p,s)\land L\land M(p,s)\implies K(p,s)$ - if $p$ counsels $s$ and all counseling meetings are on campus, and $p$ meets with $s$, then, at some point, $p$ and $s$ must both be on campus. From (2), we know that Helen is a professor and from (1) we know that all professors counsel at least one student. The conjunction of (1) and (2) then implies that there is a student $s$, such that $C(\text{Helen},s)$. Likewise, from (6), we know that $M(\text{Helen},s)$ must be true. Finally, $C(\text{Helen},s)\land L\land M(\text{Helen},s)\implies K(\text{Helen},s)$ ($L$ is always true). Therefore, at some point Helen must be on campus.

Symbolic:

$$Q:=\text{Helen}\in P\land(\forall p\in P.\exists s\in S:C(p,s))\implies \exists s\in S:C(\text{Helen},s)$$

$$U:=\text{Helen}\in P\land(\forall p\in P.\exists S_p\subseteq S:(\forall s\in S_p.M(p,s)))\implies \exists S_{\text{Helen}}\subseteq S:(\forall s\in S_{\text{Helen}}:M(\text{Helen},s))$$

$$R:=Q\land U\implies \exists s\in S:(C(\text{Helen},s)\land M(\text{Helen},s))$$

$$L\equiv\top$$

$$R\land L\implies \exists s\in S:K(\text{Helen},s)$$

(I would appreciate if someone could double check this)

Comment: For (6), instead of defining an unspecific subset, we may assume that a professor meets all the students they cousel: $\forall p \in P \forall s \in S(A_1(p,s) \to A_e(p,s))$.

Comment: For (4), one possible improvement would be that instead of defining a 0-place predicate unrelated to your $A_3$ and stipulating that it's clear what you argue for in your last paragraph, one could make $A_2$ implicational: "If there is a conseling meeting between any p and s, p and s will be at the campus: $\forall p \forall s(A_3(p,s) \to A_2(p) \land A_2(s)$.

Comment: @lemontree Thanks! Using the implication, can I say $A_4(p,s)\iff A_2(p)\land A_2(s)$, then show that $A_3$ is true independently of $A_1$?

Comment: @lemontree Also, $S$ is the set of *all* students so $\forall s\in S.A_1(p,s)$ would mean that $p$ councils every student, that's why I used a subset.

Comment: Ad your first comment: I overlooked the fact that you already have $A_4$ for "being on campus". We don't need two of them; (3) will then just be the implicaiton $\forall p \forall s (A_3(p,s) \to A_4(p,s)$, without a need for $A_2$. (Though I think that a one-place predicate $A_4$ with $A_4(P) \land A_4(s)$ is more useful, since then the conclusion formula has the simple form $A_4(Helen)$. It shouldn't be a bi-implication though, since people might be on campus without having a conseling meeting.

Comment: Ad your second comment: That's why the formula is not $\forall p \forall s (A_3(p,s))$ (which would be "Everyone counsels everyone), but $\forall p \forall s (A_3(p,s) \to A_2(p) \land A_2(s))$ ("For any pair of persons p,s, *if* p counsels s, *then* they have counsel meetings").

Comment: BTW, you might want to consider using more meaingful names for your predicates than $A_1, ..., A_4$.

Comment: studying your answer, it helps a lot to see the conversation between you and lemontree, i am learning a lot of things using it

Comment: just to make more sense, can i transform all the sentences to first order logic and from there deduct the conclusion?

Comment: @lemontree - could you please have another look at the question now? could you help me with the conversion to first order logic please? thank you very much

Comment: @R.Burton - so basically is it also possible to infer that Helen counseled Leno?

Comment: @Avariable No. You can neither prove nor disprove that Helen counseled Leno - only that Leno is counseled by a professor and Helen counsels at least one student.

Comment: just a theoretical question: if we were talking about closed domain and closed world emphasis, could you derive that conclusion?

Comment: @Avariable If by 'closed domain' you mean that Helen is the *only* professor and/or Leno is the *only* student then yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

From "every professor counsels at least one student" and "Helen is a professor" we get :

> "Helen counsels at least one student".

From it and "every counselor meets with his counselees" we get :

> "Helen meets its student".

From it and "counseling meeting occur at the campus" we get :

> "Helen meets its student at the campus".

This implies that both Helen and the student counseled (?) by Helen are in the campus.

*In order to formalize it, you have to do some more work*...